# search suggestions for NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextfield

I am interested in doing a "Google search suggestions" like for a NSTextField. I didn't find enywhere how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [NSTextControlTextEditingDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate) methods for autocompletion. [Here is an example](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/161228-auto-complete-in-an-nstextview.html) for NSTextView that can easily be adapted. The key method is:

```
- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable/disable case sensitiveness in autocomplete without implementing such method ?

Comment: Is there a way for the completion list to span the entire width of the  text field instead of just partially when you've already typed the first word into the text field?

Comment: Provided link is dead.